# Using Stanford CoreNLP/NER to extract titles (of books, articles, etc)?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

Is there some sequence of tags that could possibly indicate a title among a webpage? For example, extracting the title of the book from its amazon page, where other text/sentences may have similar sentence structures. I feel like this is an extremely fundamental task but cannot figure out exactly how to do it with Stanford's NER/CoreNLP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A solution without using the CoreNLP library - If you are looking for a title on a webpage, why not parse the `<title>` tag?

For example, the title for the amazon book page for the Hunger Games ([http://www.amazon.com/Hunger-Games-Trilogy-Boxset/dp/0545626382/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1386299491&sr=1-2&keywords=hunger+games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0545626382)) is:

> The Hunger Games Trilogy Boxset: Suzanne Collins: 9780545626385: Amazon.com: Books

Of course, title tags depend on the website, and they can either relate to the page or just be generically the title of the overarching website.

Comment: Hmmm. I was thinking more of being able to extend it to extracting titles of research papers from a specific professor's website, so it doesn't work out too well in this application. If the pdfs had some version of this title labeling that might be plausible, but unfortunately it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a sequence of html tags is not really an NLP problem. See [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). You can write a set of regex / xquery / etc. rules to detect the titles in your specific corpus. Pdfs and other documents also have some sort of markup you can exploit, see the [tika parser](http://tika.apache.org/).

For scientific articles you can easily count on the title being the first thing before a couple of newlines, or something like that.